# jQuery - replicate date from field 1 to field 2

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently looking to run a simple script using jQuery and TamperMonkey as I'm doing a recurent job which is time consuming and that should be pretty basic, not sure how to achieve the below (I've recorderd a gift) - I'm new to jQuery/coding, but searching arround, using this:

```
//Get
var IPG = $('#txt_name').val();

//Set
$('#txt_name').val(IPG);
```

might be where to look at?

the script should scan the field IPG ID where -1 are present, copy the name from the channel description and copy it to IPG description

https://gyazo.com/f4bd243827df598edfdd78ec1a2d53b5

any help in achieving this would be appreciate,

many thanks,

Comment: Please "the script should scan the field IPG ID where -1 are present, copy the name from the channel description and copy it to IPG description" rewrite this in a  meaningful way so we can help.

Comment: You are getting the value of `#txt_name` and setting it back into `#txt_name`. Just correct your selectors.

Comment: As Alexandru pointed out, at a guess `$('#txt_name').val(IPG);` maybe should be `$('#txt_description').val(IPG);`? Assuming txt_description is the ID of your description field? Otherwise you're just copying it back into where it came from.

Answer (score 0):

I named HTML elements' ids by myself because I simply don't know what are those fields' id named in your app.

What you are trying to achieve it is really simple and this code can do you the trick:

```
var IPG = $('#IPGid').val();
if (IPG==-1)
{
var toCopy  = $('#ChannelDescription').val();
$('#IPGDesc').val(toCopy);
}
```

**Note:**

1. This can only be done once the page is loaded it is not live for every action.
2. This cannot treat all lines of the table you should figure your way out of how turning it dynamic to the whole table.

Comment: Excellent, I will give a try - I need to find the field ID name, to prevent the issue with the page to be fully loaded, we might want to add a button to toggle the action - I'm new to java and tampermonkey but I'll give a try